# Which C++ library for ESRI shapefiles to choose?

Tags: c++, shapefile, gdal

Does anyone have an experience in processing (reading) [ESRI shapefiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile) from C++?

I have found at least 2 open source libraries: [ShapeLib C library](http://shapelib.maptools.org/) and [OGR](https://gdal.org/programs/index.html#vector-programs). Which one is better? Does anybody used one of them? How about the experience?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've found them both to be ok, but I'd choose the ShapeLib library as ogr is a bit heavy/weird for its purpose.

The shapefile format is very simple; if you only have to access a specific/simple set of  shapefiles you could consider reinventing the wheel and write the code to access them yourself. I've done this in an embedded app and it didn't take much more time then using these libs.

Comment: Decided to use ShapeLib, thank you very much. In our case, it makes no sense to redevelop a code that has been already tested with wide variety of applications using the lib.

Comment: Hi, sorry for my questions, just want know how to render the shapefiles ? I meaning is draw the map data ? any open source code can be use for this purpose ? 

Thanks for your reply .

Regards

Comment: @Robin, your best bet to getting an answer to this question is to search the internet. The next best bet is to post this as a _separate question_ - comments are not the appropriate place to begin a new line of inquiry.

Answer (score 23):

The [OGR Shapefile](https://gdal.org/ogr/drv_shapefile.html) driver from [GDAL/OGR](https://gdal.org/) directly uses implementation of Shapelib, so there is no difference actually. If you check the OGR source tree, you will find Shapelib files like [shpopen.c and dbfopen.c](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/ogr/ogrsf_frmts/shape?rev=18473).

Also, [Frank Warmerdam](https://web.archive.org/web/20131226093519/http://home.gdal.org/warmerda/) is the author of both, Shapelib and OGR and I can confirm myself that Frank keeps the shpopen.c and dbfopen.c in synch between Shapelib and OGR.

To summary, there is no difference between Shapelib and OGR regarding the implementation of Shapefile format specification.